# Laravel - How to get selected tags in edit mode with select2

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

When I create a record with select2 it's working fine. It saved into the database separated by commas for example like ABC, ABCD, XYZ okay no problem.

But When I edit the record how can do that like auto selected tags in appearance who is associated with that particular record. Like if in appearance field, there are tags like ABC, ABCD, XYZ whenever I edit the record these tags will be auto selected and I can remove this.

In edit mode

```
 <select id="tag_list" name="tag_list[]" class="form-control" multiple>
  //How can I get selected tags when Edit it with the particular record here.

   </select>
```

This is related to my previous Discussion.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-i-can-do-such-functionality-like-autocomplete-multiple-tagging-with-laravel

When I use options in looping it does not work How can I resolve this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Explode your string to each tag, when you build the options add the selected attribute to each exploded tag, change your select2 to show the selected as tags

```
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
   tags: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks but I want like when I edit the record if the records have tags then it automatically shows as the selected tag. hope it does make sense.

Comment: @KrishnaGupta yes you need to map the result from the db with the options and add the attribute selected to the values from the db

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537250/preselect-the-select-option-using-php  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627902/laravel-form-input-multiple-select-for-a-one-to-many-relationship is this what you need ?